# Как можно обойти принудительное завершение параллельного потока после завершения главного JAVA

Tags: java, асинхронность

Я делаю асинхронный метод, который создает новый поток и, собственно, выполняет метод асинхронно. Распараллеливаю поток с помощью класса CompletableFuture.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что если асинхронный метод не успевает завершиться раньше главного потока, то при завершении главного потока, принудительно завершается и мой асинхронный метод. **Конкретно не работает при исполнении в обычных классах**.

Пробовал на servlet'ах, асинхронный метод успешно доходит до своего логического завершения вне зависимости от главного потока.

Если сталкивались с таковым, с радостью почитаю ваши решения и предложения.

Возможно, будет понятнее, если я приведу пример. Мой асинхронный метод тратит на обработку 20 секунд, но главный метод заканчивается раньше и обрубает работу асинхронного.

```
public class SomeClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeClass.waitAsync();
    System.out.println("main thread finished");
}

public static CompletableFuture<Boolean> waitAsync() {

    CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> threadWait());

    return completableFuture;

}

public static boolean threadWait() {

    try {
        System.out.println("Async method started");
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        System.out.println("Async method finished");
        return true;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
  }

}
```

Таким образом, в консоль выведется:

```
Async method started    
main thread finished
```

Comment: Каким образом завершается главный поток? Вы останавливаете программу? Если да, то как?

Comment: Создайте демона ^_^

Comment: @Bleser зачем? По завершении программы JVM как раз-таки сворачивается, не дожидаясь завершения daemon-тредов. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-

Comment: @Artem Konovalov, главный просто успевает выполнить все действия раньше асинхронного и сам завершается. Добавил код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вся проблема в том, что CompletableFuture supplyAsync(Supplier supplier) использует внутри себя  ForkJoinPool.commonPool().
[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-][1]
А вот джавадок для ForkJoinPool.commonPool()
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--
То есть всё умирает, когда кончается метод main.
Добавьте логирование в вашу лямбду, и вы увидите, что внутри supplyAsync(Supplier supplier) орудует daemon-тред.

```
.supplyAsync(() -> {
  System.out.println("Current thread is daemon: " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
  return threadWait();
});
```

Получим:

```
Current thread is daemon: true
Async method started 
main thread finished
```

Так как JVM сворачивается, не дожидаясь завершения daemon-тредов, очевидно, что ждать завершения работы в supplyAsync в данном случае никто не будет.

Выход - использовать перегруженный метод supplyAsync(Supplier supplier, Executor executor), передав ему какой-нибудь экзекьютор, который оперирует non-daemon тредами, например:

```
public static CompletableFuture<Boolean> waitAsync() {

    CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> {
      System.out.println("Current thread is daemon: " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
      return threadWait();}, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

    return completableFuture;

  }
```

Аутпут:

```
    Current thread is daemon: false
    Async method started
    main thread finished
    Async method finished
```

**UPD**
Как совершенно справедливо отметил  @Artem Konovalov, если мы передаём в метод свой Executor и просто забываем о нём, программа никогда не завершится самостоятельно, т.к. треды в пуле сами не умрут. Поэтому необходимо сохранить ссылку на передаваемый ExecutorService и завершить его работу самостоятельно. Например, так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService =Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    waitAsync(executorService);
    executorService.shutdown();
    System.out.println("main thread finished");
  }

  public static CompletableFuture<Boolean> waitAsync(ExecutorService executor) {

    CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> threadWait(), executor);

    return completableFuture;

  }
```

В данном случае программа дождётся завершения задачи и завершится.
Вообще, тут достаточно много нюансов. Боюсь, в одном вопросе/ответе всё не охватить.

Comment: все работает, отличное объяснение, спасибо! Возможно, я пока плохо разбираюсь в теме, но как понять какой именно экзекьютор оперирует non-daemon тредами?

Comment: @Adey да, в принципе, любой из класса Executors) Они используют по дефолту ThreadFactory, которая порождает non-deamon треды. Если необходимо переопределить это поведение, можно передать свою кастомную ThreadFactory при вызове метода создания экзекьютора

Comment: В таком виде в котором вы указали в примере будет провоцироваться утечка памяти + программа не завершится. тред пул нужно выносить в поле и проверять его перед завершением главного потока на наличие работающих и запланированных на выполнение задач

Comment: @Artem, да, вы правы, мне стоило об этом написать.

Comment: @Artem Konovalov, утечка памяти будет из-за незакрытых потоков?

Comment: @Artem Konovalov, Просто тогда получается, если такой асинхронный метод делать в сервлете, то на каждое обращение будет открываться и не закрываться новый поток? Мне просто надо знать, как их правильно закрывать с таком случае. Не выключать же каждый раз Executor?

Comment: @Adey Выключать ExecutorService нужно будет только по окончании жизненного цикла сервлета, например, в методе destroy(). Сами ТредПулы и то, как они обращаются с тредами, очень разные. Например в экзекьюторе, использованном в данном примере, вообще только один тред, всегда. Вопрос очень объёмный, на эту тему материала очень много.

Answer (score 1):

Вижу следующее решение данной проблемы - сохранять все `CompletableFuture` и проверить их на завершенность перед завершением главного потока.

Примерно так:

```
public class Main {
  private final Set<CompletableFuture<?>> futures = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.waitAsync();
    System.out.println("main thread finished");

    main.futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
  }

  public CompletableFuture<Boolean> waitAsync() {
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Main::threadWait);
    futures.add(completableFuture);
    completableFuture.whenComplete((e, v) -> futures.remove(completableFuture));
    return completableFuture;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но получается, что если асинхронный поток будет работать дольше, то главный будет ждать его завершения? Мне кажется тут сама суть асинхронности теряется. Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Конечно, главный поток будет ждать. Но суть асинхроности не теряется, главный поток может заниматься в этом время другими вещами, ждать он будет только в момент когда ему уже нечем будет заняться